# ClassCastException occurs when I am trying the Blaze Persistence documentation sample

Tags: java, blaze-persistence

I'm trying the sample code in the document '[1.5. First criteria query](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/core/manual/en_US/#first-criteria-query)' section. The code is below,

```
CriteriaBuilder<Cat> cb = cbf.create(em, Cat.class, "c")
    .where("c.age").betweenExpression("5").andExpression("10")
    .where("SIZE(c.kittens)").geExpression("2")
    .orderByAsc("c.name")
    .orderByAsc("c.id");
```

And when I add the following code ClassCastException occurs.

```
List<Cat> results = cb.getResultList();
```

I created the github public repository, so you can check the code [here](https://github.com/ecormaksin/blaze-persistence-sample/blob/e3976491f013f8aca740165ff0033c2bdba4e3d5/src/test/java/com/example/blazepersistencesample/infrastructure/jpa/repository/JpaCatRepositoryTest.java#L205).

Does anyone know where I am wrong?

I created the project with Spring Boot.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `Cat` entity has a `kittens` field which is not a plural attribute, but an integer. Change it to `@OneToMany Set<Cat> kittens` and the query will work. Unfortunately the problem is on the Hibernate side i.e. Hibernate does not print a proper error message but instead fails with the exception.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

add logs pls next time they are always helpful

I recommend u to run cb.getResultList() in debug and understand what comes

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will do it from next time.